# Need scan through text files in a directory and filter based on loop results

Tags: c#

I have a program that scans through text files in a directory, loops through each line and parses based on a prefix in each line. The program acts as an extractor, extracting a tif image from a Base64 string on prefix "Hxx". When the program gets the image from line "Hxx", it simply deletes the original file.

What I would like to do is keep the filtering conditions for line "TXA" but instead of converting the string on line "Hxx" to an image and deleting the file, I would like to keep the entire contents of the file. Basically, only using the program to parse and filter through the text files based on conditions for line "TXA".

I know in `case` "TXA" of my `foreach` loop, I need to save the entire file into a memory stream to re-write the file towards the end of the program. I'm just not sure how at the moment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// This method will open, read and parse out the image file and save it to disk.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static bool ParseHFPFile(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
    {
        List<MemoryStream> tiffStreamList = new List<MemoryStream>();

        // 1. grab file contents.
        string fileContents = ProgramHelper.GetFileContents(inputFileName);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContents))
        {
            return false; // errors already raised.
        }
        Log("[O] ", false);

        // 2. split file contents into a string array.
        string[] fileContentStringList = fileContents.Split('\r');
        if (fileContentStringList.Length == 0)
        {
            Log(" ERROR: Unable to split file contents on [CR] character.");
            return false;
        }

        // 3. loop through the file lines and parse each "section" based on it's prefix.
        string mrn = string.Empty;
        string dos = string.Empty;
        string imgType = string.Empty;
        foreach (string line in fileContentStringList)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                continue;
            }
            string prefix = line.Substring(0, 3);
            switch (prefix)
            {
                case "MSH":
                    break;
                case "EVN":
                    break;
                case "PID":
                    mrn = line.Split('|')[3].Split('^')[0];

                    break;
                case "PV1":
                    dos = line.Split('|')[44];
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dos))
                    {
                        dos = dos.Substring(0, 8);
                    }
                    break;
                case "TXA":
                    imgType = line.Split('|')[2].Split('^')[0];
                    if (imgType == "EDH02" || imgType == "EDORDH")
                    {
                        Log("[NP]");

                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case "OBX":
                    break;
                case "Hxx":
                    // 0 - Hxx
                    // 1 - page number
                    // 2 - image type
                    // 3 - base64 encoded image.

                    // 1. split the line sections apart based on the pipe character ("|").
                    string[] hxxSections = line.Split('|');
                    byte[] decodedImageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hxxSections[3].Replace(@"\.br\", ""));

                    // 2. create a memory stream to store the byte array.
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    ms.Write(decodedImageBytes, 0, decodedImageBytes.Length);

                    // 3. add the memory stream to a memory stream array for later use in saving.
                    tiffStreamList.Add(ms);
                    break;
                case "Z":
                    break;
            }
        }
        Log("[P] ", false);

        // 4. write the memory streams to a new file.
        ImageCodecInfo icInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Single(c => c.MimeType == "image/tiff");
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder enc = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag;
        var ep = new EncoderParameters(1);

        // 5. create references to the EncoderValues we will use
        var ep1 = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
        var ep2 = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
        var ep3 = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);

        string newOutputFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFileName) + @"\";
        string newOutputFileName = newOutputFilePath + mrn + "_" + dos + ".dat";
        bool success = false;
        int suffix = 1;
        while (!success)
        {
            if (File.Exists(newOutputFileName))
            {
                newOutputFileName = newOutputFilePath + mrn + "_" + dos + "_" + suffix + ".dat";
            }
            else
            {
                success = true;
            }
            suffix++;
        }
        Log(string.Format("[NewFile: {0}] ", Path.GetFileName(newOutputFileName)), false);

        var strm = new FileStream(newOutputFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        System.Drawing.Image pages = null;

        int frame = 0;
        int pageCount = tiffStreamList.Count;

        Log("[WT:", false);
        try
        {
            foreach (MemoryStream m in tiffStreamList)
            {
                if (frame == 0)
                {
                    ep.Param[0] = ep1;
                    pages = Image.FromStream(m, false, false);
                    pages.Save(strm, icInfo, ep);
                }
                else
                {
                    ep.Param[0] = ep2;
                    if (pages != null)
                        pages.SaveAdd(Image.FromStream(m, false, false), ep);
                }

                if (frame == pageCount - 1)
                {
                    ep.Param[0] = ep3;
                    if (pages != null)
                        pages.SaveAdd(ep);
                }

                frame++;
                Log(".", false);
                //m.Close();
                m.Dispose();
            }
            Log("]");

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(" EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain in one short sentence what are you asking?

Comment: @codeman061988 Well, it seems like a lot of work for something simple. Why don't you just make two `List<string>` and save the `TXA` file names in the first, and all the other in the second. At the end you delete those from the second list and you do what you want with the files from the first list?

Comment: @Maxim I basically need the code to produce a text file instead of a tif file, grabbing all of the information instead of just the data parsed from line "Hxx".

Comment: Leron I could probably do that. I know it seems more complicated than it should be. There's more to the program than what I have here and I'm re-writing someone else's code to perform a different task.

Comment: I looks like I already have a string array that consists of the text contents broken into lines...`fileContentStringList`.. Below the loop, I need to somehow use that existing `FileStream` method and add the `fileContentStringList` to the file being created at the moment. I've tried `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(strm, fileContentStringList);` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok, not using The `FileStream`...just need `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newOutputFileName, teststring);` I made my own string and tested this and it works. Now I just need to use `fileContentStringList`.

Comment: Finally..I got what I wanted from it...`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(newOutputFileName, fileContentStringList);`. @Leron, I'm going with your answer because the the program already put the file contents into a string array. I just needed to put the content back into the file once parsing is complete. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy that you succeeded with your task. If my comment helped you solve the problem I'm gonna post it as an answer so you can accept it if you want.

So, instead of looking for more complicated ways you can just go and create two `List<string>` like:

```
List<string> TXA = new List<string>();
List<string> FilesForDelete = new List<string>();
```

and then in your code, depending on what you want to do with the file:

```
if (fileIsTXA)
{
  TXA.Add(fileName);
}
else
{
  FilesForDelete.Add(fileName);
}
```

Later on you can use those two lists to extract the file names and do whatever you want with them.